# python code that is locally vs pip installed works differently

Tags: python, import, pip

this is mad_import.py

```
import pieqt
import sys
import importlib
def mad_import(module):
    #for module in modules:
    libs = [m[0] for m in filter(lambda a: type(a[1]) == type(module), module.__dict__.items())]
    print(libs)
    for lib in libs:
        __import__(lib)
    generate_runtime_python_imports(libs,module)
    generate_runtime_python_imports_from(libs)
    importlib.import_module('runtime_python_imports_from')
    # __import__('runtime_python_imports_from.py')
    #return libs



def generate_runtime_python_imports(libs,module):
    dic = module.__dict__.items()
    moduleNames = []
    roukzouk = []
    for key in dic:
        for lib in libs:
            print(key[1])
            if key[1]!=None and lib in str(key[1]) and 'from' not in str(key[1]):
                print(True)
                roukzouk.append(str(key[1]))
                # sys.exit()
            if key[1] != None:
                d=str(key[1])+'s'
            moduleNames.append(d)

    print('-'*100)
    import_line_text = ""
    for import_line in roukzouk:
        for lib in libs:
            import_line = import_line[import_line.find(lib):].rstrip("'>")
            print(import_line)
            import_line_text+="import "+import_line+"\n"
    with open("runtime_python_imports.py", "w") as runtime_python_imports:
        runtime_python_imports.write(import_line_text)

def generate_runtime_python_imports_from(libs):
    import_line_from_text = ""
    for lib in libs:
        import_line_from_text += "from "+lib+" import *\n"
    with open("runtime_python_imports_from.py", "w") as runtime_python_imports_from:
        runtime_python_imports_from.write(import_line_from_text)

# import importlib
# for module in moduleNames:
#   if module not in {'__name__','__doc__','__package__','__loader__','__spec__','__file__','__cached__','__builtins__'}:
#       importlib.import_module(module)
# print(QApplication)

# mad_import(pieqt)
```

this is pieqt.py

```
import PySide2
import PySide2.QtCore
from PySide2.QtGui import*
from PySide2.QtWidgets import*

QApplication = PySide2.QtWidgets.QApplication
QTextEdit = PySide2.QtWidgets.QTextEdit
QLabel = PySide2.QtWidgets.QLabel
QPushButton = PySide2.QtWidgets.QPushButton
QCheckBox = PySide2.QtWidgets.QCheckBox
QMainWindow = PySide2.QtWidgets.QMainWindow
QVBoxLayout = PySide2.QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout
QWidget = PySide2.QtWidgets.QWidget

def user_function():
    print("I am a user function")
callbacks = []
def run():
    global callbacks
    for callback in callbacks:
        callback()
def callback_user_functions():
    global callbacks
    for callback in callbacks:
        callback()
def add_function(function):
    global callbacks
    callbacks.append(function)
def main():
    print("Enter your code below!!!")
    global callbacks
    add_function(user_function)
    run()
    #callback_user_functions()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and this is test_mad_import.py

```
import pieqt
from pieqt import *
import mad_import

mad_import.mad_import(pieqt)
print(QTableView)
```

When I run test_mad_import.py in that folder, it works correctly(i can call mad_import.mad_import(pieqt) and QTableView exists)

But when I go to another directory to test it, I pip install my package(which I uploaded in GitHub, and used twine), but I can't call mad_import.mad_import(pieqt).
It gives TypeError: 'module' object is not callable(if i do mad_import(pieqt))
And AttributeError: module 'foo' has no attribute 'foo'(when i do mad_import.mad_import(pieqt))

So is there a differentiation in pip installed software versus having all files locally in a folder?

Comment: This question really needs example `foo.py` and `bar.py` files, along with precise instructions about how to recreate both setups.

Comment: https://github.com/rivenblades/mad_import

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/mad_import/

Comment: This is not a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This is the actual code of the problem

Comment: Yes, but you can surely reproduce the same problem with *less* code; for example, we don't need any Qt-related stuff to reproduce an import error.

Comment: Ok. My problem is that, with 2 files, when i run them in their folder they run correctly but when i go to another folder and have the 2 files as a package in pypi which i have installed, they dont run correctly

Comment: Well the problem was the structure of my code.I needed to put setup.py inside source files